# Разложение диапазона дат Python

Tags: python

Имеется 2 поля с "датой начала" и "датой окончания" в котором представлено несколько диапазонов.
Необходимо разложить все диапазоны дат. 
Например: 
    исходник: date_start/date_end
              2017-12-01/2017-12-26
    нужно получить: 2017-12-01
                    2017-12-02
                    2017-12-03

Для разложения самой даты, использую:

```
def generate_range_dates(start_date, end_date) -> list:
    date_1 = min(start_date, end_date)
    date_2 = max(start_date, end_date)

    items = [date_1]

    while date_1 < date_2:
        date_1 += DT.timedelta(days=1)
        items.append(date_1)

    return items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def d2s(date):
        return date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    start_date = df.Date_start
    end_date = df.Date_end

    items = generate_range_dates(start_date, end_date)
    print(items)  

    for date in items:
        print(d2s(date))
```

Но как мне передать в start_date и end_date даты из моего Pandas? 
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Мне кажется, вы изобретаете колесо. Есть же методы pandas типа `pd.date_range`. В любом случае, дополните вопрос в соответствии с рекомендациями MaxU.